# Why are imported SASS styles being purged by PurgeCSS when using camelCase?

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass, node-sass

I am trying to combine CSS-modules and PurgeCSS to get module scoping and a light CSS bundle.

I have been able to accomplish this using syntax like `styles["my-class"]` but would prefer `styles.myClass` (which works, but gets stripped out for imported SASS within SASS files).

SASS from a local file works as expected, but SASS @imported from `node_modules` or another file doesn't work with camelCase references.

In the below code, I will get an output like:

```css
.Component--container--AfniF {
  margin: 1em;
}
```

but all the imported SASS that I reference in the component as `styles.myClass` is purged.

But, when referenced like `styles["my-class"]` everything works as expected and I get output like:

```
.Component--my-class--6Mlw4 {
  color: purple;
}

.Component--container--AfniF {
  margin: 1em;
}
```

Any ideas?

```
// otherstyles.scss
.my-class {
    color: purple;
}
```

```
// Component.scss
@import "otherstyles";

.container {
    margin: 1em;
}
```

```js
///Component.js
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import classnames from "classnames";
import styles from "./Component.scss";


export default function ({ data }) {
    return <div className={classnames([styles.myClass, styles.container])}>
```

```js
//webpack.config.js

...
           {
                test: /.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            modules: true,
                            camelCase: true,
                            importLoaders: 1,
                            sourceMap: true,
                            localIdentName: "[name]--[local]--[hash:base64:5]",
                        },
                    },

                    {
                        loader: "postcss-loader",
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "@americanexpress/purgecss-loader",
                        options: {
                            paths: [path.join(__dirname, "src/**/*.{js,jsx}")],
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader",
                        options: {
                            includePaths,
                            outputStyle: "expanded",
                            sourceMap: true,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Dealing with the same issue now.

Comment: @tjq check this https://github.com/FullHuman/purgecss/issues/163